How can i copy a vm snapshot to storage account in Azure?
I can successfully create a VM disk snapshot using az cli.
How can i copy the snapshot to an azure storage account using az cli ?


How can i copy the snapshot to an azure storage account using az cli ?

You can use the command below to copy the VM snapshot to an Azure storage account using Azure CLI.
First, copy the VM snapshot URL from the portal:
Azure Portal > Snapshots > select your snapshot > Snapshot export > generate URL.

Command:
az storage blob copy start --account-name "venkat679" --destination-blob "abcd.vhd" --destination-container "test" --account-key "<Your account key>" --source-uri "<snapshoturl>"

Output:
{
  "client_request_id": "bc99xxxxxee-a269-00155df677e8",
  "copy_id": "xxxx",
  "copy_status": "pending",
  "date": "2024-04-04T06:15:30+00:00",
  "etag": "\"0x8DC546EA152C803\"",
  "last_modified": "2024-04-04T06:15:30+00:00",
  "request_id": "8xxxxx,
  "version": "2022-11-02",
  "version_id": null
}


It takes some time to finish the copy process, and after some time, it will reflect in your storage container.
Portal:
The file has been successfully copied to an Azure storage container.

Reference:
az storage blob copy | Microsoft Learn
Update:
Here is the full script with output to copy snapshot to blob storage in bash.
subscriptionId="xxxx"
resourceGroupName="xxx" 
snapshotName="snap1"
sasExpiryDuration=3600
storageAccountName="venkat123"
storageContainerName="test"
storageAccountKey="xxxx"
destinationVHDFileName="sample.vhd"

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --account-name $storageAccountName --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName  --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas  

Output:


Here is the link to export snapshot using CLI:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/copy-snapshot-to-storage-account

Check the network setting whether it is in enabled to all networks

Add the error screenshot in the question with commands.

Command and just the error.

Update in question with full commands.

Where are you running this code?

Try in azure Cloud shell in portal.

Try in bash environment in portal it copied https://i.imgur.com/MGqCU4R.png

I actually worked it out and found the issue

How come when i save to a storage account the size of the snappshot is 0 bytes ?

Please raise new question with brief explanation.

Use the 'az storage blob copy start' command.
Authenticate to your Azure account:
az login

Initite the copy operation:

bash
az storage blob copy start --destination-blob <blob-name> --destination-container <container-name> --account-name <storage-account-name> --source-uri <source-uri>

You can monitor the copy operation status:
bash
az storage blob copy show --container-name <container-name> --account-name <storage-account-name> --name <blob-name>

