How can I copy blobs between Azure Storage accounts using the Azure CLI?
I am trying to copy a blob snapshot from one Azure Storage Account to another using the following:
az storage blob copy start \
--destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName \
--destination-container $storageContainerName \
--account-name $storageAccountName \
--account-key $storageAccountKey \
--source-uri $sasString

I can see them in the Storage account and then to see the status of the copy I run
az storage blob show \
--account-key $storageAccountKey \
--account-name $storageAccountName \
--container-name $containerName \
--name $blobName \
--query "{name:name, url:url, size:properties.contentLength, type:properties.contentType, copyStatus:properties.copy.status}" \
--output json

The issue is that every time, the Copy Status fails.
How can i copy the snapshot to a Storage account using the Azure CLI?

Is "allow cross-tenant replication" enabled on the source storage account? You can find the setting under Data Management > Object Replication > Advanced settings.

It made no difference , it still failed !

Is there some sort of third party tool i can use ? Azure resource manager or something ?  Or can i use azcopy

I would suggest to use Azcopy tool for easy and fast copying process.

I have and every time it says operation cancelled. Are you able to give me an example , thanks

@Sandy Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


I have and every time it says operation cancelled. Are you able to give me an example .

In my environment, I had a snapshot with name venkatsnap and it has size of 2048GiB.
Portal:

Now, I copied snapshot URL from the portal.
Portal-> snapshot->snapshot export ->Generate URL -> copied the URL.
Portal:

I copied SAS token for azure blob storage from the portal:
Portal:

Using the azcopy command I can be able to copy the snapshot to Azure blob storage.
Command:
azcopy copy "https://md-f5rwtwlx3zff.z21.blob.storage.azure.net/rgz4qlhhsnl2/abcd?snapshot=2024-10-09T04%3A59%3A13.7110808Z&sv=2018-11-09&sr=bs&si=redacted&sig=redacted" "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/abcd.vhd?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-10-09T13:04:35Z&st=2024-10-09T05:04:35Z&spr=https&sig=redacted" --recursive=true

Command and output:
PS C:\Users\zzzzz> azcopy copy "https://md-f5rwtwlx3zff.z21.blob.storage.azure.net/rgz4qlhhsnl2/abcd?snapshot=2024-10-09T04%3A59%3A13.7110808Z&sv=2018-11-09&sr=bs&si=redacted&sig=redacted" "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/abcd.vhd?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-10-09T13:04:35Z&st=2024-10-09T05:04:35Z&spr=https&sig=redacted" --recursive=true

INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job 4dxxxxxxa19 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\xxx\.azcopy\4d93xxxxxa19.log

100.0 %, 1 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0.002


Job 4dxxxxx233a19 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0668
Number of File Transfers: 1
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Number of Symlink Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 1
Number of File Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Folder Transfers Completed: 0
Number of File Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Failed: 0
Number of File Transfers Skipped: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Skipped: 0
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 2199023256064
Final Job Status: Completed


Portal:
The above command successfully copied the snapshot to Azure Blob Storage.

Reference:
azcopy copy | Microsoft Learn

for the second url in azcopy , the part abcd.vhd?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-10-09T13:04:35Z&st=2024-10-09T05:04:35Z&spr=https&sig=redacted" . Now abcd.vhd is the name of the image you want in storage account , but how did you get the rest of it , ie sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-10-09T13:04:35Z&st=2024-10-09T05:04:35Z&spr=https&sig=redacted

You can see tha third picture where i can generated through portal.

yep have tried , it keeps failing . I even wait 2hrs

Can you paste the error with screen shot how you are doing?

this is a manual process. I need to do it all automated using azure cli ?

Then refer my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78271931/how-can-i-copy-a-vm-snapshot-to-storage-account-in-azure/78272071#78272071
